# How to define tile provider (H.map.provider.TileProvider)?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get the the tiles in a bounding box to pass them to the PDE. I am using the following code, but I am not sure how to define the H.map.provider.TileProvider.

```
// I don't know how to define the tileProvider (this is what I have for now)
var tileProvider = new H.map.provider.TileProvider({
min: 12,
max: 15,
});

var overlayLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(tileProvider, {
// Let's make it semi-transparent
opacity: 0.5
})

var boundingBox = new 
H.geo.Rect(map.getViewBounds().getTop(),map.getViewBounds().getLeft(),map.getVi 
ewBounds().getBottom(),map.getViewBounds().getRight());

var zoomLevel=14;
var cacheOnly=false;
var prioCenter=new H.math.Point(42.36099070901032,-71.09613451879883);

overlayLayer.requestTiles(boundingBox, zoomLevel, cacheOnly, prioCenter)
```

Would you please let me know how to define the TileProvider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create instance of TileProvider since it is an abstract class. You can create instance of its children(ImageTileProvider, MarkerTileProvider etc. refer documentation in developer site).

Example:

```
  // Create your own LocalObjectProvider and add some hierarchical objects:
  myProvider = new H.map.provider.LocalObjectProvider();
  myMap.addLayer(new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(myProvider));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Considering this, I am still having a hard time to find the tiles in a bounding box for a given zoom level. Would you please give me an example of how to find the tiles in such a case? i.e. requestTiles(boundingBox, zoomLevel, cacheOnly, prioCenter)

Comment: You have to first determine the pde layer you want. Based on that, you can calculate level, tileX, tileY using mathematical calculations. https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/resource-tile.html

Comment: Thanks. I already knew how to find the tile for a given lat/lon position using the mathematical calculations. My question is that how can I find all the tiles in a given bounding box (i.e. having locations of the four corners of a rectangle, how to find the tiles within it?). My naive way of calculation is to loop in the bounding box and find the tile for all the lat/long positions in the given boundary. I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to do it using the API?

Answer (score 0):

**I know it has been a year for this question, but an answer might help others:**

```
(function (map) {
    tileProvider = new H.map.provider.ImageTileProvider({
        min: 5, //min zoom factor
        max: 12,  //max zoom factor
```

define a getURL function which takes 3 parameters:

```
getURL: function (column, row, zoom) {
```

here you should return a url contains the tiles. You could get it over an API or even local. At the end pass the 3 factors: zoom / col / row  .. or how your image is called

In the next example the image is stored in a folder named after the zoom number and the image called for example: 12-16.png

```
            return `.../${zoom}/${column}-${row}.png`;
        }
    });
```

Notice that if you get your tile images from an external provider
You should acknowledge the provider with the Copyrights method:

```
tileProvider.getCopyrights = function (bounds, level) {
    return [{
        label: "© ....", // this will appear under the map
        alt: "© ...."
    }];
};
```

Then define a layer that contains the tiles.

```
var overlayLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(tileProvider);
```

Add the layer to the map (I am assuming you have already initialized a map)

```
 map.addLayer(overlayLayer);
})(map);



(function(map) {
    tileProvider = new H.map.provider.ImageTileProvider({
        min: 5,
        max: 12,
        getURL: (column, row, zoom) =>
            `${site_url}/images-folder/tiles-folder/${zoom}/${column}_${row}.png`,
    });
    tileProvider.getCopyrights = (bounds, level) => {
        return [{
            label: "©...",
            alt: "©..."
        }];
    };
    let overlayLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(tileProvider);
    map.addLayer(overlayLayer);
})(map);
```